# Deploying reactJS application - routing issues in production mode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-s3, react-router-dom

I've got some routing issues after deploying in production mode. 
(My app runs on an aws S3 Bucket) everything works fine only routing has some issues.

Matching not known Routes are the Problem. I have the following routing:

```JSX
import {BrowserRouter as Router, hashHistory, Switch, NavLink, Route} from "react-router-dom";

<Provider store={store}>
    <AppContainer>
        <Router history={createHistory}>
            <div>
                <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                    <div className={i.content}>
                        {/*Switch is for Error Routing*/}
                        <Switch>
                            <Route exact path="/" component={() => (<Logins foo={"test"} loginHandler={this.props.loginHandler}/>)}/>
                            <Route path="/logout" component={() => (<Logins foo={"test"} loginHandler={this.loginHandler}/>)}/>
                            <Route path="/signup" component={() => (<SignUp loginHandler={this.loginHandler}/>)}/>
                            <Route path="/imprint" component={() => (<Impressum/>)}/>
                            <Route path="/verification/:verificationToken/:verificationEmail" component={() => (<Verification/>)}/>
                            <Route component={() => (<Error/>)}/>
                        </Switch>
                        <div className={i.footer}>
                            <a href="https://johner-institut.de" target="_blank">{t('application:made')} <img src={jilogo} width="8px;"/>
                            </a> | <NavLink to="/imprint">{t('application:imprint')}</NavLink> | <LanguageChooserSmall/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ThemeProvider>
            </div>
        </Router>
    </AppContainer>
</Provider>
```

Known Routes working fine. But in error case the Switch should affect all not known routes should be redirected to `<Route component={() => (<Error/>)} />` but that's not working ...

what could be the problem?

Comment: d'you get any errors or anything? 'not working' is not very descriptive..

Comment: It returns a 404 not found

Comment: and the 404 is coming from the server?

Comment: yes from the S3 bucket

Comment: but It should route to the error case

Comment: have you tried setting `response page path` to `index.html` in clodfronts custom error response setting?

Comment: @VF_ just trying to get cloudfront working. at the moment I just call the S3 url

Comment: @VF_ that works fine thanks! will you post as answer then I can vote it up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the `response page path` to `index.html` in the `custom error response` setting in cloudfront.